# tbl_regression (gtsummary) warning

Tags: gtsummary

Trying to understand how to fix this new warning that I get when I knit a .qmd file, running the same tbl_regression command that I have done previously without issue.

```
lm(y ~ x, data = dat) |>
  tbl_regression(intercept = T) |>
  add_glance_source_note() |> 
  as_flex_table() |> 
  flextable::font(fontname = "Consolas", part = "all")

Usage of empty symbol '' with footnote should not happen, use `add_footer_lines()` instead, it does not require any symbol. This usage will be forbidden in the next release. Please, wait for 10 seconds!
```

How do I keep the glance source note without the warning showing?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that flextable had deprecated this syntax! Thanks for reporting. As far as suppressing this message in a qmd doc, you'll want to add `#| warning: false` or `#| message: false` for the chunk. Details here: https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html

Comment: If it works for you, you can avoid the 10 second delay by using `add_glance_table()` or installing an older version of flextable before the 10 second penalty was added.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. add_glance_table doesn't really work for me because I like the compactness of the add_glance_source_note. Using the former does indeed make the warning and delay disappear. However, if I add either `#| warning: false` or `#| message: false` to the chunk, the warning and delay persist. Is the 10 sec penalty staying in place because that makes tbl_regression quite painful to use (and I otherwise think it is fantastic)

Comment: Ahhh, is the delay nothing to do with gtsummary but a result of flextable?

Comment: Yes, it's a flextable penalty/note. I already wrote the fix and waiting for the final checks to complete. It'll be fixed in the gtsummary dev version either tonight or tomorrow (depending on how long the checks take).